# filterFilter not working in 1.6 angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs

```
$scope.$watch('search', function (newVal, oldVal){
                $scope.filtered = filterFilter($scope.items, newVal);
                $scope.totalItems = $scope.filtered.length;
                $scope.noOfPages = Math.ceil($scope.totalItems / $scope.entryLimit);
                $scope.currentPage = 1;
            }, true);

    `ReferenceError: filterFilter is not defined
        at scripts.js:39404
        at Scope.$digest (scripts.js:17814)
        at Scope.$apply (scripts.js:18080)
        at done (scripts.js:12210)
        at completeRequest (scripts.js:12436)
        at XMLHttpRequest.requestLoaded (scripts.js:12364)`
```

Please suggest some solution how to use filterFilter in  1.6

Comment: What is filterFilter? There's no function in angular named like that.

Comment: have you passed `filterFilter` into your controller?